# Loss of Data in IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, deployment, indexeddb

We store real-time data in IndexedDB, and occasionally, data is unexpectedly deleted from IndexedDB despite having sufficient storage capacity. One identified scenario involves data removal when the user opts to clear data upon closing the browser, but other similar bugs persist.

Are there any effective techniques to prevent data loss in IndexedDB? I am currently utilizing the 'idb' library, which can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/idb.